# Controlling how elasticsearch fields are tokenized for faceting

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch (and the underlying Lucene engine).

We're storing some metadata about documents eg a single document might be described as:

```
UniqueHash: ABC123
CreatedBy: John Smith
ApplicationName: MSExcel
ContentType: application/vnd.ms-excel
WordCount: 7000
...
```

This all works very well for indexing/searching but when we come to faceting, things get interesting.

Faceting on (say) `CreatedBy` would return

```
John: 1
Smith: 1
```

or on ContentType

```
application: 1
vnd.ms: 1
excel: 1
```

neither of these is desirable. I have no direct control over the contents of the field (that is to say, I can't change the underlying data). I can perform a transform on the way in but that would result in storing dodgy data just so the searching works as expected which feels like the wrong approach.

How can I convince elasticsearch to treat the whole contents of each field (or at least of specified fields) as the value to use for faceting?

Comment: @javanna Thanks I didn't spot the typo - long day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index your field twice using [Multi Field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type.html) Type. After reindexing, you will be able to continue using analyzed version of your field for search, and use "untouched" version of the field for facets.

Comment: That sounds promising, thanks - I'll read the linked article now